# A name in literature for a certain kind of 2-categories

Tags: simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories, 2-categories

Let $tr_2: \mathrm{sSet} \to \mathrm{sSet}_{\le 2} $ be the 2-truncation functor.

Let $C$ be a 2-truncated simplicial set such that every horn $tr_2( \Lambda^2_1) \to C$ extends to $tr_2(\Delta_2) \to C$, not uniquely.

1. Is there a common name to refer at this? Something like weak 2-category?
2. (curiosity) Are "weak 2-categories" equivalent to 2-coskeletal quasicategories?

Comment: I don't think a 2-truncated simplicial set with $\Lambda^2_1 \rightarrow \Delta^2$ horn extensions doesn't have enough structure to be considered any kind of category. There are two problems:

 1. You would want your 2-simplices to be your 2-cells, but you how would you encode composition of 2-cells without higher simplices?

 2. Even though $\Lambda^2_1 \rightarrow \Delta^2$ horn extensions give you a notion of composition of 1-simplices, you need higher simplices for that composition to be well-defined and associative up to homotopy.