# Simplicial sets with horn filling conditions up to some fixed degree

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

Let $X_\bullet$ be a simplicial set such that some horn filling condition (inner horns fill/inner horns fill uniquely/all horns fill) holds up to dimension $n$ (i.e. for $\Lambda_i[p]$ for all $p\leq n$). Is there a name for the resulting structure on $X_\bullet$? Of course, if $n=\infty$ then $X_\bullet$ is a quasi-category/1-category/Kan complex.

For example, naively, I would expect that if all inner 2-horns in $X_\bullet$ fill then it has some sort of composition structure, but it fails to be associative; if all inner 2-horns and 3-horns fill then it is "a bit" associative, but higher associativity fails, and so on.

*Edit:* Here's a related question that I would also be satisfied to hear an answer to: if all horns fill up to dimension $n$, then is it true that the simplicial homotopy groups are well defined up to dimension $n-2$ (or something similar)? The proof is relatively straightforward for $n=2$ but I don't think that it generalises, since the description of $\pi_0$ is much simpler than that of higher $\pi_n$.

Comment: one related fact is that, if only 2-horns fill, then it is still true that the simplicial $\pi_0$ calculates the topolgical $\pi_0$ (a fact which is true for all $\pi_n$ if all horns fill)

Comment: relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354132/a-name-in-literature-for-a-certain-kind-of-2-categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I've never encountered a name for the class of simplicial sets you describe (and can't imagine them being worthy of more than a nonce word), I can answer your related question in the affirmative. This follows from the combination of two observations:

- The $(n-2)$nd homotopy group of a pointed Kan complex depends only on its underlying $(n-1)$-skeleton. This should be immediately clear from any combinatorial definition of homotopy groups.
- If a simplicial set $X$ has the property you describe, then there exists a Kan complex $Y$ and a weak homotopy equivalence $X \to Y$ which is a bijection on underlying $(n-1)$-skeletons. For such can be obtained from $X$ by running the small object argument with $k$-horns for $k > n$, and filling these horns does not alter the underlying $(n-1)$-skeleton.

Comment: This is the sort of argument I was hoping would hold, but I'm always wary of small object things, so thanks for sketching it out. Is there anything you could say about the "interpretation" part of the question? I guess your comment on the other answer suggests that they are somehow opposite/dual to n-hypergroupoids.

Comment: What is the relationship between the Y thus constructed and some coskeleton of $X$?

Comment: @TimPorter The only relationship is that they have the same $(n-1)$-coskeleton. Note that every Kan complex arises as such a $Y$; indeed, every Kan complex can be considered as such an $X$.

Comment: @Tim With respect to interpretation, the best I can say is that, just as an arbitrary simplicial set can be thought of as a presentation for a Kan complex, a simplicial set with all horn fillers below a certain dimension can be thought of as a presentation which is complete in those lower dimensions but not necessarily in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the related notion of $n$-hypergroupoid that was introduced year ago by Duskin and Glenn. e.g.  P. Glenn, Realization of cohomology classes in arbitrary exact categories, J. Pure. Appl. Alg., 25, (1982), 33–105, and also more recently by T. Beke, Higher Cˇech theory, K-theory, 32, (2004), 293 – 322, or J. P. Pridham, Presenting higher stacks as simplicial schemes, Advances in Mathematics, 238, (2013), 184 – 245 and also going back to the study of T-complexes, e.g. in N. Ashley, Simplicial T-Complexes: a non abelian version of a theorem of Dold and Kan, Dissertations Math., 165, (1989), 11 – 58.  I suspect that none of these will precisely fit your request but they show that the area has been quite extensively studied.  Another related source is Zhu's paper on n-groupoids, and stacky groupoids, International Mathematics Research Notices 2009, I think.

Looking through those you will find lots of names!!

Your question could be interesting to rephrase in terms of  simplicial groups or simplicially enriched groupoids. You could then apply the Cordier simplicial nerve to examine the resulting quasi-category, but can use more algebraic methods.

Finally there are interesting related questions for algebraic / categorical models of homotopy $n$-types e.g. Conduché's 2-crossed modules, Loday's $cat^n$-groups. There one has that the analogue of the interchange law may fail. In 2-crossed modules the failure is measured by a pairing which covers

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that n-hypergroupoids are in a sense opposite to the questioner’s notion: they are simplicial sets with unique horn fillers above, rather than below, a certain dimension.

Comment: This is a nice collection of references to look at, thanks! But yes, at a first glance, this notion does seem to be sort of dual to what I describe.

Comment: If I recall correctly, in Duskin's work an n-hypergroupoid satisfies the Kan condition in dimensions up to n and then is n+1-coskeletal above that, i.e. unique filler. Applying the n+1 coskeleton functor to X gives something of that form... or am I misunderstanding the question?   Of course this just handles Kan conditions, but some of Beke's constructions might be adaptable to a quasi-category context.

Comment: Another point worth making is that if one starts with any chain complex of abelian groups that is zero up to dimension n, then the (Dold-Kan) corresponding simplicial abelian group will be trivial in dimensions less than n, and so have the underlying simplicial set has only trivial horns in low dimensions, and the rest should be clear. Triavial horns with trivial fillers!!!  My point being that the classes you are seeking have to include such examples as these.

Comment: oh that's a very interesting example, definitely something for me to think about, thank you!